# How to assert disabled option from the list?

Tags: c#, automation, atata

I need advice, how to assert the disabled option from the list that it is disabled using Atata or else?

```
<option value="Test" disabled="">Test</option>
```

Comment: it could be done via Jest lib.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a property in page object:

```
public Select<_> SomeSelect { get; private set; }
```

Do the following in the test:

```
pageObject.SomeSelect.Options[x => x == "Test"].Should.BeDisabled();
```